# Same View, different displays, One page, same exposed filters. Possible?

Tags: views

I want to list my content categorically within view. The problem is that I want all of it to be filtered through exposed filters.

Here is what Content Type looks like:-

### Content Type (MyContent)

- Title
- Body
- Category `(it has three categories in it "Category1, Category2 and Category 3". User has to selects one when entering the content)`

Now I created a view which lists all of the content linearly (like a normal list) and I have exposed filters on top, which filter the content, but now I am not sure how to proceed when I have to show the content as:-

[image]

Any Idea what I should do to achieve this? What should I do in this scenario?

I'll be grateful to you valuable assistance.

Best.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve.  You wrote "The problem is that I want all of it to be filtered through exposed filters," but by default all content displayed in a view IS filtered through any  exposed filters, so I don't see the problem.  Are you trying to group the results by category?

Comment: I agree with Patrick Kenny, I would either recommend doing a Group By (and Group By the categories) rather than filter.

Comment: What I am trying to achieve is that I want to group the results by the category values. The picture above shows the exact result I am looking for. The whole grouped result is being filtered by exposed filters so you are absolutely correct there.

Answer (score 0):

So I solved this by using Attachments in my view.

Each attachment had a separate filter.